# Why isn't this login form working?

Tags: php, mysql, oop, authentication

I have a class to login users, but when I test it using the form and bad credentials, I'm still getting 'success.' Could someone point me in the right direction?

```
include('User.datatype.php');

$usher = new Authenticator;
$usher->checkCreds();
$usher->ensureHasAccess();

Class Authenticator {
    protected $user;
    protected function getCreds() {
        if (!isset($_POST['login']))
            throw new Exception("There was an error processing your request", 1);
        else if ($_POST['username'] == '' || $_POST['password'] == '')
            throw new Exception("You must enter a username and password", 1);
        $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $this->user = new User;
        $this->user->username = $username;
        $this->user->password = $password;
    }

    public function checkCreds() {
        $this->getCreds();
        if (empty($this->user->username) || empty($this->user->password))
            throw new Exception("Error Processing Request", 1);
        include('dbconnect.php');   // Normally I'd store the db connect script outside of webroot
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name;", $db_user, $db_password);
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = :uname AND password = :pword');
        $stmt->bindParam(':uname', $this->user->username);
        $stmt->bindParam(':pword', $this->user->password);
        $stmt->execute();
        $status = $stmt->fetch();
        $this->user->status = $status;
        print $status;
        return $this->user->status;
    }

    protected function createSessionID() {
        $seshID = mt_rand(99999, 1000000);
        return $seshID;
    }

    protected function startSession() {
        if (empty($this->user->status))
            throw new Exception("There was a problem connecting to the database", 1);
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['username'] = $this->user->username;
        $_SESSION['id'] = createSessionID();
        $secret = $_SESSION['id'];
        header('Location:index.php?' . $secret);
        return true;
    }

    protected function hasAccess() {
        $this->startSession();
        if (!startSession())
            throw new Exception("You do not have access to this page.", 1);
        return true;
    }

    public function ensureHasAccess() {
        if(!$this->hasAccess())
            throw new Exception("You are not logged in.");
        print 'Welcome, ' . $this->user->username;
    }
}
```

HTML form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="authenticator.php" method="post">
            <p>username: <input type="text" name="username" /></p>
            <p>password: <input type="password" name="password" /></p>
            <p><input type="submit" name="login" /></p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your "hasAccess" function, aren't you suppose to be calling "startSession" instead of "session_start"?

Comment: The phrase 'success' does not exist in your code.

Comment: @Touch I fixed that, but it didn't work.
MikeB Sorry, allow me clarify: I don't receive any errors

Comment: dump out your incoming $_POST vars are they actually being passed into the class with data or are they passing blank?  Is it actually hitting the success point after your isset validation?

Comment: Is it actually performing the login then failing or is it failing with the "You must enter a username and password" section of code before its even doing the rest of the processing/session setting etc?

Comment: I'm receiving exception "there was an error connecting to the database."

Comment: now we know where to look so we can ignore everything below about sessions etc so its an issue with your connection :)

Comment: I think so, too. I wonder if it's the $stmt->fetch(). Should I be using fetchObject() or fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)?

Comment: Are your variables all populated (dump them out) $db_host $db_name $db_user $db_password.  Also try putting a try {} catch {} around the connection `try { $pdo = new PDO etc... } catch catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}`

Comment: I actually just checked that, and yes they are populated. I think my fetch() statement is messed up, because $this->user->status doesn't become populated.

Comment: try the fetch object then just remember it'll set your status as an object so you'll have to reference the element inside the object

Comment: so I can't simply do $this->user->status = $stmt->fetchObject() ?

Comment: You could but then your $this->user->status is holding a complete object so if you ever need to reference anything so if you want to reference a column in future it'd be $this->user->status->column etc not just $this->user->status.  Actually looking at your code you don't reference the contents of status anywhere so why not just set it true or false default to false with true set if login success it'll be more memory efficient etc and save you passing an object around for the entire life cycle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you got

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

at the top of your index.php page?

and var_dump($_SESSION); to see what information it holds

As far as i am aware you would have to have session_start(); on any page were you want your session info to exist.

Answer (score 1):

Except the fact that I have already pointed out the "session_start()" that is in the middle of the page as a possible logic error, if as you say it is fixed, I have a bad feeling about this line.

```
 $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = $this->user->username AND password = $this->user->password');
```

The single quotes could be preventing the variables in the $this->user from being changed to the real values. That could not be there error, but I am more familiar with MySQLi, haven't used PDO yet. But I suggest you try change this to:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = '.$this->user->username.' AND password = '.$this->user->password);
```

Just a possible hint. Don't know if it's the one though.

Comment: very little point preparing a statement and embedding the variables directly into the prepare.  Either do a direct execute or do a proper prepare so :username :password and then `->bindparam(":username",$this->user->username);` etc

Comment: I would +1 (you seem to have spotted the bug), but your suggestion opens him up to SQL injection attacks. [Remember Bobby](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: That is true. I am just fixing the error. It's up to her to take security into consideration. With MySQLi, I would use question marks than bind. But I as I have said, I haven't used PDO yet. So I was just showing her a possible fix. It's up to her to take care of the SQL injection by replacing my code where appropriate. But I have noticed it and thanks for pointing it out. I hope she sees it.

Comment: I used :uname and :pword and then bindParam() for each of them.

Comment: Either question marks or direct variable replacement would work for PDO binding either is fine :)

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your logic.  `if (!session_start())` starts the session and if it fails to start, throws the exception.  You need to check if the user is authorized a different way, such as using `$this->user->status = $status;` to determine if the user is authorized.